# Qt - mainwindow class object in another class doesn't work well

Tags: qt, class, object, slot, mainwindow

```
void MyAnotherClass::mySlot(){
MainWindow window;
window.myFunction();}

void MainWindow::myFunction(){

qDebug() << "THIS qDebug works well but ui do NOT";

ui->textEdit->setText("Why i do not working?");
}
```

Why qDebug in this situation works fine, but ui->... doesn't? How to fix it?

**EDIT:**  Solution:
`QPlainTextEdit *pointer;
MainWindow constructor{
pointer=ui->qPlainTextEdit;}

Some Another's class method{
pointer->appendPlainText("It works");
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create new instance of `MainWindow` class inside `MyAnotherClass::mySlot()`. When this slots ends this instance is deleted. So you can't see any changes.

```
void MyAnotherClass::mySlot() {
    MainWindow window;  //new instance created
    window.myFunction();
} //here this instance deleted
```

Instead of this you should have pointer to your main window somewhere inside your `MyAnotherClass`:

```
MyAnotherClass
{
     .......   
    private slots:
        void mySlot();

    private:
        MainWindow* _mainWindow;
      ...............
};
```

and then you can do somethins like this:

```
void MyAnotherClass::mySlot() {
    _mainWindow->myFunction();
}
```

Of course you should somehow init this pointer before you can use it.

Comment: How to init this pointer? Do you know good way to do this?

`class MyAnotherClass : public QPlainTextEdit{
    private: 
        MainWindow* _mainWindow;
}`

Comment: There could be several ways depends on your code design. You can pass it into constructor, or some method. Or you can make `MainWindow` a singleton.

Comment: [mainwindow.cpp](https://codepaste.net/ebe9mm) [mainwindow.h](https://codepaste.net/g3nf65) [myqplaintextedit.h](https://codepaste.net/ba8kjc) 

My another class is **MyQPlaintTextEdit** and code you can find in **mainwindow.cpp** in **exit_slot()** and **on_pushButton_clicked()**; Can you tell me how can I use that pointer in my case?